# NodeJS Buttons, Examples?

Tags: node.js, button, kik

I have been experimenting for several days now with kik bots using NodeJS. However I have not, despite my research, been able to find any examples of the implementation of buttons using NodeJS. I am referring to the keyboard options the bot presents you with to choose from, so you don't have to type your response in.

other info:
I am using ngrok,
I am testing this under the android kik app,
I am running the kik server on Linux mint, 
I have tried using on line web services, but find they overcomplicated things or are often broken.

Comment: node.js is server-side. buttons is client-side. totally separate.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're referring to is called a "Suggested Response" - it's documented here:

https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#keyboards

If you're using our node lib:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kikinteractive/kik#Message+addResponseKeyboard

Hope this helps.

David @ Kik